# Refresh button inside manipulate

Tags: manipulate

How do you add a refresh button to

```
Manipulate[RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[p], 10], {p, 0, 1}]
```

that will re-evaluate `RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[p], 10]` when clicked?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following works :

```
   Manipulate[
     Typeset`update$$; 
     RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[p], 10], {p, 0, 1},
     AppearanceElements -> "UpdateButton"]
```

[image]

To update press the button "U" at the top-right.
Of course, if you move the cursor it updates too.

Answer (score 8):

```
Manipulate[
 r; 
 RandomVariate[BernoulliDistribution[p], 10], 
 {p, 0, 1}, {{r, True}, None},
 Button["refresh", r = ! r]]
```

[image: Out]